# Windows Phone 7.1 Project References

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, dependencies, project, solution

I have solution with multiple projects:
ProjectA
ProjectB
ProjectC

The relationship between the project should be:
ProjectA > References > Project B
ProjectB > References > Project C
ProjectC > No References

Currently when trying to implement the relationship described above I get an exception(can't provide the exact exception right now), that ProjectC assembly is missing from ProjectA.

In know that it's possible in Android, but is it possible on WP platform?

**Edit:** 
I know that adding a reference of ProjectC to ProjectA will solve the exception, but it's not my goal.

Comment: You should add reference Project C to Project A too. Because Project B depends on Project C.

Comment: Why didn't you reference C from A?

Comment: Cause my goal is to have only one reference in ProjectA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup you describe is possible, but only if ProjectA does not reference any types from ProjectC in its source.  If ProjectA references any type from ProjectC (even indirectly), then you will have to add the reference.  There is no way around this, because for the compiler to build ProjectA, it must be able to resolve all the types in its source code.

For example, let's say we have the following projects:

ProjectC:

```
public class C
{
    public void CTest() { Console.WriteLine("C"); }
}
```

ProjectB:

```
public class B
{
    public C GetC() { return new C(); }
}
```

ProjectA:

```
public class A
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        // b.GetC();
    }
}
```

The above will compile, but if you attempt to uncomment the last line in Main, you will get a compiler error:

> The type ProjectC.C is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to assembly 'ProjectC, ...'

---

One possible way around this would be to use dynamic types.  Dynamic typing causes type resolution to be deferred until runtime, which means that the following modification will compile and run successfully.  (I wouldn't recommend this approach -- because you lose compile-time safety and Intellisense support -- unless there is a really compelling reason.)

ProjectC:

```
public class C
{
    public void CTest() { Console.WriteLine("C"); }
}
```

ProjectB:

```
public class B
{
    public dynamic GetC() { return new C(); }
}
```

ProjectA:

```
public class A
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.GetC().CTest();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I agree with you. Better to add same reference to different projects than to use Dynamic types.